# What function looks like $\overbrace{}$?

Tags: functions

Here's my awesome drawing:

[image]

Basically it's a function that takes a high (or infinite) value at $0$, then falls off logarithmically for a while before falling off exponentially.

It doesn't need to be symmetric, it would be ok if the negative $x$ values were 
reversed in sign or something like that. I really only care about $x\ge0$.

Edit: I would prefer if the function is *not* periodic.

Comment: Awesome drawing, dude.

Comment: It's surprising to me how many upvotes this got when you consider the lack of rigor in the question. I've seen so many questions shot down because they are of the form: " I know the first 4 numbers of the sequence... what is it? ". I fail to see how this question is any different... I guess an 'awesome' drawing makes all of the difference

Comment: @jameselmore I fail to see the similarities between the sequence questions you mention and this question. The question is about finding a function that looks like this image shown, not implying there is a single function that they are looking for. People (like myself) may find these kind of questions interesting, thus up-voting it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You almost *literally* describe a function satisfying your description: e.g.

$$ f(x) = -(\ln(x) + \exp(x)) $$

Tweak the constants to taste. Absolute value to make it symmetric: i.e. play with $A,B,C,D$ to shape it how you like:

$$ f(x) = A - B \ln |x| - C \exp(D |x|) $$

Here's a sample function with $A=20$, $B=5$, $C=1/20$ and $d=20$.

[image: sample plot]

[generated by wolfram alpha](http://20%20-%20log%7Cx%7C%20*5%20-%20exp%7C20x%7C/20%20for%20x%20from%20-0.3%20to%200.3)

Comment: This is almost certainly the right answer; how could it not be, given the first sentence?

Comment: :tear: it's beautiful

Comment: By the way, why no coefficient inside the \ln?

Comment: @rhombidodecahedron: I put one in at first, but quickly remembered $\ln |Ex| = \ln |E| + \ln |x|$, so it would be redundant with $A$. However, $\ln(|x| + F)$ could be useful if you don't want the peak at $0$ to go all the way to $+\infty$.

Answer (score 8):

Motivation: "Falls off logarithmically to the right" and "falls off exponentially to the right" means that it increases exponentially in one direction and decreases exponentially in the other.

This sounds like a bit like a [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function), which models exponential growth as we approach the lower $y$-bound and upside-down exponential growth near the upper $y$-bound (like $y=e^x$ and $y=-e^{-x}$ respectively), but it's rotated inconveniently.

So I looked up its inverse (the [logit function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit)), which has the form $\log(\frac{x}{1-x})$. After some modifications to reflect across the $x$-axis and $y$-axis, I got the [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20-log%28%7Cx%7C%2F%281-%7Cx%7C%29%29):
$$f(x)=-\log{\frac{|x|}{1-|x|}}$$
(Try $f(ax), af(x), f(x)+a,$ etc. to scale/translate as needed)

Answer (score 6):

For instance:
$\arccos(|x| -1)$
[Plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5BArccos%5BAbs%5Bx%5D-%201%5D%2C%7Bx%2C-2%2C2%7D%5D)

Comment: If you alter it to $y=\cos^{-1} (0.4|x|-1)$, it looks almost identical to OP's graph.

Answer (score 3):

How about [$\frac{x^2-1}{x^2(x-2)(x+2)}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28x%5E2-1%29%2F%28x%5E2*%28x%2B2%29*%28x-2%29%29+from+x+%3D+-2+to+2)